# Why 中華民國 = Republic of China?

Tags: translation, terminology, place-names

According to google translate and other dictionaries, "republic" means "共和國" in Chinese.

Comment: Historical reason:the name 中华民国 preceded its English translation in time.

Comment: @TooskyHierot, when 中華民國 was established, I imagine its official English translation is (at least should be) also determined.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer: because Sun Yat-sen proclaimed it so. In a [1916 speech](http://sunology.culture.tw/cgi-bin/gs32/s1gsweb.cgi?o=dcorpus&s=id=%22SP0000000706%22.&searchmode=basic) given in Shanghai, he asks the question:

> 何以不曰「中華共和國」，而必曰「中華民國」？
>
> Why instead of 中華共和國, must one say 中華民國?

The reasons he gives boil down to drawing a distinction centred on the 民: saying that this is the fundamental difference between Qing dynasty feudalism and the Ancient Greek republic (and by extension, modern China).

Although 共和 carries the idea of the *res publica* of Latin, he acknowledges this, and proceeds to give 民 greater importance.

As of early 2019, the [only states](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%E6%B0%91%E5%9B%BD-%E5%85%B1%E5%92%8C%E5%9B%BD.2017769/) to officially use 民國 are the Republic of China and the Republic of Korea.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow the meaning of "民國" is lost in its official English translation.

Answer (score 3):

民国 and 共和国 mean exactly the same. However, nowadays we prefer 共和国 to 民国 as the translation of “republic”.

---

### Etymologies (word origins)

The native Chinese term 民国 is actually a mimicked term from 王国 and 帝国.

> 王国 “king’s state”, i.e. kingdom
>
> 帝国 “emperor’s state”, i.e. empire
>
> 民国 “people’s state”, i.e. republic

The Japano-Chinese term 共和国 is a Chinese term borrowed from the Japanese term 共和国 (きょうわこく), which means “gonghe state”. The [Gonghe Regency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonghe_Regency) (西周共和时期) was an interregnum period in Chinese history from 841 BC to 828 BC, and China had some similarities to a republican state during that period. As a result, “gonghe state” is modernly used to refer to a republican state.

To sum up, 民国 and 共和国 mean exactly the same.